# Finder QuickLookUIService blank windows

Tags: finder, bug, high-sierra

After upgrading to "macOS High Sierra 10.13" "Finder Preview" (QuickLookUIService? the space bar feature) will sometimes show a blank window when navigating with the arrow keys. I used to use this feature to verify I was uploading the correct images.
Is this a known bug, and are there any workarounds?

Comment: Any solution to this yet? I'm experiencing the same issue...

Comment: @Bokdem Apple said they might have it fixed for the next release, I'll be using Debian instead.